# Swift : How to share image of imageview?

Tags: ios, swift

imageview load image from Url

this code for save the image

```
let indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathsForVisibleItems().last!
let cell = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PhotoBrowserCell
if cell.imageView.image == nil{
    print("image nil")
} else {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cell.imageView.image!, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
}
```

`cell.imageView.image` I do not know how to make it work with share,
What is the best way to share image from imageview

**Update**

i did it ^_^

this code work fine for sharing from my imageview

```
   let indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathsForVisibleItems().last!
        let cell = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PhotoBrowserCell
         if let image = (cell.imageView.image)
        {
            let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: [])
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: share you code, where you get image

Comment: Don't use your collection view cells to store data. They are view objects. You should have a model object (possibly as simple as an array or an array of arrays) that stores the data displayed into your collection view cells.

Comment: Please clarify do you want to know how to share an image with other users using the built-in methods? If so, please restate. Did you search for keywords on SO before posting this question? This is a common process so search the site for the answer.

Comment: @TommieC. i know how to share local image , i am try to share  image from (url) imageView , and yes i searched but i did not found anything

Comment: You, probably, try to check image and print log before then it's set by download from URL block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did it ^_^

this code

```
   let indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathsForVisibleItems().last!
        let cell = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PhotoBrowserCell
         if let image = (cell.imageView.image)
        {
            let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: [])
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're asking how to implement sharing in iOS? That's a fairly complex subject. You want to read up on `UIActivity` in the Xcode docs, and perhaps find a tutorial on implementing sharing in iOS.